Could not resolve dependencies for project : mule-policy:1.0.0
I am developing a MuleSoft custom policy and have created a new policy using the Maven archetype command as follows:
mvn archetype:generate -Parchetype-repository \
-DarchetypeGroupId=org.mule.tools \
-DarchetypeArtifactId=api-gateway-custom-policy-archetype \
-DarchetypeVersion=1.2.0 \
-DgroupId=${orgId} \
-DartifactId=${policyName} \
-Dversion=1.0.0 \
-Dpackage=mule-policy

This generates the policy project, which I then import into Anypoint Studio. I have made changes to the template.xml and policy.yaml files accordingly.
Since I am aware that the http-transform-extension dependency is exclusive to enterprise accounts and I am using a free account, I don't need this dependency. Therefore, I have commented it out in the pom.xml:
       <dependencies>
        <!-- This extension allows to easily update HTTP attributes from a policy -->
        <!-- Full documentation: https://docs.mulesoft.com/api-manager/2.x/http-policy-transform -->
           <!--  <dependency>
                <groupId>com.mulesoft.anypoint</groupId>
                <artifactId>mule-http-policy-transform-extension</artifactId>
                <version>${httpPolicyTransformVersion}</version>
                <classifier>mule-plugin</classifier>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.mule.connectors</groupId>
                        <artifactId>mule-http-connector</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency> -->
        </dependencies>

However, when I try to deploy my policy using mvn clean deploy command, I get the following error:
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project test: Could not resolve dependencies for project 8************************4:test:mule-policy:1.0.0: The following artifacts could not be resolved: com.mulesoft.anypoint:mule-http-policy-transform-extension:jar:mule-plugin:3.1.0 (absent): com.mulesoft.anypoint:mule-http-policy-transform-extension:jar:mule-plugin:3.1.0 was not found in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 during a previous attempt. This failure was cached in the local repository and resolution is not reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]

The stack trace points to a dependency issue with mule-http-policy-transform-extension, but i have commented the dependencies part out.
Here is my full pom.xml file
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>82**********************</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>

    <name>test</name>
    <description>this is a test policy</description>

    <packaging>mule-policy</packaging>

    <properties>
        <mule.maven.plugin.version>4.1.0</mule.maven.plugin.version>
        <exchange.url>https://maven.anypoint.mulesoft.com/api/v1/organizations/82aa4097-da3d-42bb-967f-780c99073db4/maven</exchange.url>
        <http.policy.transform.extension>3.1.0</http.policy.transform.extension>
    </properties>

       <dependencies>
        <!-- This extension allows to easily update HTTP attributes from a policy -->
        <!-- Full documentation: https://docs.mulesoft.com/api-manager/2.x/http-policy-transform -->
           <!--  <dependency>
                <groupId>com.mulesoft.anypoint</groupId>
                <artifactId>mule-http-policy-transform-extension</artifactId>
                <version>${httpPolicyTransformVersion}</version>
                <classifier>mule-plugin</classifier>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.mule.connectors</groupId>
                        <artifactId>mule-http-connector</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency> -->
        </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.mule.tools.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>mule-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${mule.maven.plugin.version}</version>
                <extensions>false</extensions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>upload-template</id>
                        <phase>deploy</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>deploy-file</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <repositoryId>exchange-server</repositoryId>
                            <url>${exchange.url}</url>
                            <file>${project.basedir}/${project.artifactId}.yaml</file>
                            <generatePom>false</generatePom>
                            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                            <artifactId>${project.artifactId}</artifactId>
                            <version>${project.version}</version>
                            <packaging>yaml</packaging>
                            <classifier>policy-definition</classifier>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>exchange-server</id>
            <name>Corporate Repository</name>
            <url>${exchange.url}</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
    </distributionManagement>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>mule-plugin</id>
            <name>Mule Repository</name>
            <url>https://repository.mulesoft.org/nexus/content/repositories/public/</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>anypoint-exchange-v3</id>
            <name>Anypoint Exchange V3</name>
            <url>https://maven.anypoint.mulesoft.com/api/v3/maven</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>

Any thoughts or help? thanks in advance
Ps: this is my jdk version java version "1.8.0_401"

Where did you see it being only for enterprise users?

And what you trying to do exactly? Share the policy.

@aled mule-http-policy-transform-extension comes under enterprise repository only
https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/3.9/configuring-maven-to-work-with-mule-esb#referencing-mulesofts-enterprise-repositories

I tried deploying whatever comes OOTB when you generate a policy but still the same error

Not sure what possibly you could do without depending on the HTTP connector. Currently policies are associated with REST/SOAP HTTP requests. Probably that component is required. Separately to that, the link you shared is for the repository configuration. It doesn't mention mule-http-policy-transform-extension explicitly.

you see these are two different modules, one is http-policy which is used for REST/SOAP communication. The other is http-policy-transform-extension which is used for modification of http requests and responses and it is an extension available only at Mule's Enterprise repositories and not on public repos.
